# What is difference between Send Selected Item to and Send Row of data to for Web Part Connection? I want to Connection Between this two web part

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part

Hey I am creating the connection between two Web Part. When I select the List View Web part that time connection property show  **Send Row of data to** and when I select the Data List Web Part that time show connection property  **Send Selected Item to**. I want to show selected Item information in to another Web part. But when I user List view web part that time not showing selected item information but when I select the Data List Web Part that time it work. I want to create the connection between List View WebPart to Business Related Web Part.
[image]
 [image]

Comment: What are your options? Have you tried using the connections?

Comment: Yes i tried but i am not able to create the connection between List view Web part to  Business Related Web Part. . Result not showing when i create the connection between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding **What is difference between Send Selected Item to and Send Row of data ?**

**Send Row of data to** : is a connection option when you try to connect list view web part with another web part.

**For Example :**

You have list 1 (Parent) and list 2 (child) and you need to `filter data from` list 2 to list 1 it's the same of `send row of data` from list 1 to list 2.

[image]

**Send Selected Item to** : is a connection option when you try to connect `Business Data Related List` with `Business Data List` to get filter items fom `Business Data List` to `Business Data Related List`

[image]

**Note :**

- Business Data List : Displays a list of items from an external list.
- Business Data Related List : Displays a list of child items related to a parent item from an external list. **Requires an association**.

For more Details Check [Use the Business Data Web Parts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-Business-Data-Web-Parts-6ebda742-7563-43a5-9d68-136a00cd4121)

Regarding  **I want to create the connection between List View WebPart to Business Related Web Part.**

It looks Yes you can do this from `Business Related Web Part` Connection > Get Filter Value from `ListView` as shown below.

[image]

But unforthenatlly , because of `Business Related Web Part` depend on specific External content Type **Association** so `Business Related Web Part` web part can connect to web part(s) that provide this **related  external type**.

[image]

it's actually the selected type when you create the association as shown below

[image]

So the final result you can't create the connection between **List View WebPart** to **Business Related Web Part** and vise versa.